# Android findViewWithTag returns null

Tags: android, xml

I am using a PagerAdapter and would like to use the findViewWithTag method, however it always returns null.

In the instantiateItem i'm instantiating my page view like this

```
public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
    View pageView = getPage(position);
    ((ViewPager) view).addView(pageView);
    return pageView;
}
```

In the getPage method i'm doing this:

```
 LinearLayout pageView = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pageritem_news,null,false);
```

In a for loop i'm trying to get the views inside the pageView by tag, but it always returns null, somebody have any idea ?

Maybe the problem can caused by the pageritem_news.xml because there i'm using include to include views to the layout and  define the android:tag in the `<include />` in the xml?

**Update**
The pageritem_news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_0_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="0"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_0_middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="5"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_0_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="10"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_divider_height"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_1_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="1"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_1_middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="6"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_1_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="11"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_divider_height"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_2_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="2"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_2_middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="7"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_2_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="12"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_divider_height"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_3_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="3"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_3_middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="8"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_3_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="13"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_divider_height"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_4_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:tag="4"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_4_middle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:tag="9"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newspage_item_row_4_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/listitem_news"
        android:tag="14"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The PagerAdapter's relevant code parts:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
    View pageView = getPage(position);
    ((ViewPager) view).addView(pageView);
    return pageView;
}


private View getPage(int position) {
    LinearLayout pageView = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pageritem_news,null ,false);

    int index=0;
    View viewToBuild = null;
    while (index < mMovers.size()) {
        viewToBuild = pageView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(index));
        System.out.println("View to build: " + viewToBuild);
        if (viewToBuild != null) {
            buildNewsView(viewToBuild, mNews.get(index));
        }
        index++;
    }

    return pageView;
}
```

Comment: Show us your XML (the layout you're including and the place where it's included) and the actual invocation of `findViewWithTag`

Comment: you have your tags in `pageritem_news.xml`, but in code which you provided you looking for tags in `pageritem_movers.xml`, can you show this file as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#include-element), you can only overwrite `layout_*` attributes when using `<include />` (essentially, anything that would go into the respective `LayoutParams` object).

There is an enhancement request for this feature [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38023).

I would suggest to find a way to do what you're trying to do with IDs. For example, you can have a [TypedArray](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) of IDs that you can iterate over. You can change this array on a configuration-per-configuration basis (that way it's not in your code and you have all the benefits of defining tags in XML).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I never thought the problem will be with using the include. My other idea was with the id's list too, but i don't know why the "tags way" sounded more cool :)